# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException JavaFx WebEngine

Tags: java, javafx, webengine, stringindexoutofbounds

The following code generates a StringIndexOutofBoundsException and I'm not sure why:

```
public class Browser extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    WebPage currentPage = new WebPage();
    WebView webView = currentPage.getWebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = currentPage.createWebEngine(primaryStage);
    webEngine.load("http://algonquincollege.com");

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(webView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

I get the following errors in Eclipse:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:960)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:290)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:91)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:102)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage.flushRQ(WCImage.java:52)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.lambda$getPixelBuffer$77(RTImage.java:163)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:960)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:290)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:91)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:102)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage.flushRQ(WCImage.java:52)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.lambda$getPixelBuffer$77(RTImage.java:163)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.drawString(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:960)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:290)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:91)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:102)
at com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCImage.flushRQ(WCImage.java:52)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.RTImage.lambda$getPixelBuffer$77(RTImage.java:163)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to prevent this or handle this exception? I think it might have something to do with the URL because other sites load fine without an error.

I tried adding a Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in the start method but it didn't work.

Comment: `currentPage.createWebEngine` looks suspicious.  Why are you creating a new WebEngine instead of using the WebView’s engine?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what your error is I also couldn't run your code but here is what worked for me

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.load("http://algonquincollege.com");

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(webView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```